# Floodfill algorithm for GO

Tags: java

The floodfill algorithm is used in the bucket tool in MS paint and photoshop, but it can also be used for GO and minesweeper.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

In go you can capture groups of stones, this website portrays it with two stones.
http://www.connectedglobe.com/mindy/cap6.html

This is my floodfill method in Java, it is not capturing a group of stones and I have no idea why because to me it makes sense.

```
public void floodfill(int turn, int col, int row){
    for(int a = col; a<19; a++){
        for(int b = row; b<19; b++){
            if(turn == black){
                if(stones[col][row] == white){
                    stones[col][row] = 0;
                    floodfill(black, col-1, row);
                    floodfill(black, col+1, row);
                    floodfill(black, col, row-1);
                    floodfill(black, col, row+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It searches up, down, left, right for all the stones on the board. If the stones are white it captures them by making them 0, which represents empty.

Comment: Have you tried it in a debugger?

Comment: It's just supposed to check in the four directions, up, down, left, right. Not in that order but those 4 regions of the stone.

Comment: If it's not capturing a group of stones, what _is_ it doing?

Comment: It's not doing anything, not working at all... It's supposed to be able to replicate capturing groups of stones just like in GO the board game. Link: http://www.connectedglobe.com/mindy/cap6.html I've also tried your implementation and it still does not work.

Comment: Both the `floodfill` version Byte56 provided and my own should be able to capture groups of white tiles. Do either of them work?

Comment: Unfortunately neither work.  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/picsey.png/

Comment: Is the floodfill actually being called on any of them?

Comment: I made it get called everytime a user places a stone.

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2978/discussion-between-jonathan-hobbs-and-user1048606)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are intending to do this. The flood fill shouldn't have `for` loops in it.

```
public void floodfill(int turn, int col, int row){
    if(turn == black){
        if(stones[col][row] == white){
            stones[col][row] = 0;
            floodfill(black, col-1, row);
            floodfill(black, col+1, row);
            floodfill(black, col, row-1);
            floodfill(black, col, row+1);
        }
    }
}

public void floodfillAll(int turn){
    for(int a = 0; a<19; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b<19; b++){
            floodfill(turn,a,b);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is kind of silly. Since the flood fill should fill everything anyway. Just use the first part.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say *in what way* it's not working (is it crashing, or taking forever?). You ought to do that.

However, it strikes me as immediately absurd that your *recursive* flood fill has a loop. You could either write a loop to fill everything (which wouldn't be a flood fill), or you could write a recursive flood fill:

```
public void floodfill(int turn, int col, int row){
    if(turn == white) return;
    // also add: if 'col' and 'row' aren't in the valid range, return
    // otherwise you'll get index out of bounds errors because you will
    // eventually call to flood column -1.
    if(stones[col][row] == black) return;
    stones[col][row] = 0; // does black = 0? Saying black would be more readable
    floodfill(black, col-1, row);
    floodfill(black, col+1, row);
    floodfill(black, col, row-1);
    floodfill(black, col, row+1);
}
```

If you want to loop through every tile, you don't need a recursive flood fill. If you want to do a recursive flood fill, you don't need to loop through every tile.

Every time your old method was called it was spanning through every tile above it in the x/y direction, then calling a tile before it, which would then call every tile after it and a tile before it. I imagine your 'flood fill' would never have ended.

Comment: Nice, 11 seconds difference.

Comment: @Byte56 [Brilliant!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBh895KdXAU)

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that it's not capturing a group of stones.